# Power BI or Excel Index and Match more than 1 categories

Tags: excel, powerbi

Can you show me how to index and match formulas for more than one categories in Excel or PowerBI? or someone can advise me on how to solve my problem.
I have 2 tables different worksheet, and there are no connections. The two tables are Transaction and Agent.
I use this formula in Excel, but only to reference one column category.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Agent!A:A;MATCH(Transaction!A2&Transaction!B2;Agent!B:B&Agent!C:C;0));"")`

But I have five column categories for the reference formula.

[Transaction Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxavh.png)
[Agent Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnSF7.png)

thks for help

formula excel or powerbi index & match more than 1 categories

Comment: I usually use a helper column that concatenates the data across all the columns I'm interested in, then do a Match on that

Comment: Can you update your question and make it clear what you are needing. If there are 5 column categories to match then show that. Something like "from table a on columns A, B, C I need to get value from table B on columns X, Y, Z.

Comment: im sorry for my dull question, i just want call host name in agent sheet to transaction sheet, like date in agent sheet 6/11/2023 time 9 (should call "Andi") but when im apply  this formula '=IFERROR(INDEX(Agent!A:A;MATCH(Transaction!A2&Transaction!B2;Agent!B:B&Agent!C:C;0));"")' only can one column (categoty).

Comment: how to concaenate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TREATAS](https://dax.guide/treatas/) to construct filters on-the-fly and utilize that in a join. Such as

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Agent[f3] ),
    TREATAS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Agent, Agent[f1], Agent[f2] ),
        'Transaction'[f1],
        'Transaction'[f2]
    )
)
```